# Keycloak Get User Temporarily locked status from Rest API

Tags: keycloak

I'm using the Key cloak version above 20.0., In this is there any REST API to know whether the user is temporarily locked?

Thanks all for your help in advance.

I tried Get Representation of the user API

{{keycloak_url}}/admin/realms/{{realm}}/users/{{userid}}

In this we are getting the response "enabled": false but not able to get the temporarily locked status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the

GET /{realm}/attack-detection/brute-force/users/{userId}

to check  whether the specific user is temporarily locked, the response as follow

```
{
    "numFailures": 3,
    "disabled": true,
    "lastIPFailure": "127.0.0.1",
    "lastFailure": 1684205667502
}
```